# KernelPCA from sklearn doesn't return original data

Tags: pca, kernel-trick

If I do a transform and then an inverse_transform using PCA, I of course get the original data back.  If I do the same for KernelPCA, I don't.  Is this a property of kernelPCA or a shortcoming of the implementation?  Code is here:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA, KernelPCA
pca = PCA(n_components=2, copy=True)
kpca = KernelPCA(n_components=5,
             kernel='rbf',
             gamma=1.0, # default 1/n_features
             kernel_params=None,
             fit_inverse_transform=True,
             eigen_solver='auto',
             tol=0,
             max_iter=None)
train_set = np.random.rand(5,2)
k_transformed = kpca.fit_transform(train_set)
k_orig =  kpca.inverse_transform(k_transformed)
p_transformed = pca.fit_transform(train_set)
p_orig =  pca.inverse_transform(p_transformed)
print "Original Data"
print train_set
print "PCA"
print p_orig
print "KPCA"
print k_orig
```

Output  is here:

```
Original Data
[[ 0.60102465  0.37562677]
 [ 0.78281304  0.20575771]
 [ 0.55120131  0.31717359]
 [ 0.48216065  0.85297703]
 [ 0.77400554  0.86559728]]
PCA
[[ 0.60102465  0.37562677]
 [ 0.78281304  0.20575771]
 [ 0.55120131  0.31717359]
 [ 0.48216065  0.85297703]
 [ 0.77400554  0.86559728]]
KPCA
[[ 0.53530411  0.3594765 ]
 [ 0.51250412  0.25227312]
 [ 0.51253417  0.32343322]
 [ 0.45231888  0.55243246]
 [ 0.49755706  0.55221213]]
```

Answer (score 1):

From wikipedia - " Because we are never working directly in the feature space, the kernel-formulation of PCA is restricted in that it computes not the principal components themselves, but the projections of our data onto those components. " .  So kernel PCA only computes the final step which is the projection onto the a subspace.  There is never a unique way to recover a vector from it's projection.

Comment: If that is true, then what does the function inverse_transform do ?

Comment: For a function to have an inverse, it has to be 1-1.  Non-trivial Projections are never 1-1. Suppose you have two variables x and y so the (x,y) identifies your data and suppose that x accounts for 96% of it.  If you are only given x, one can't determine what y is.  In PCA, one starts with (x,y) and one is told that x has enough of the variance.  But one has (x,y) and the matrix (matrices) that gives the projection onto y.  With kernel PCA one merely knows that there is a non-linear embedding $R^2 \hookrightarrow  R^N$  and one is given $f_1(x,y) $, one doesn't have $f_1, \ldots f_N$ .

Comment: In the PCA example (to use your notation) I used both x and y, so the inverse_transform was exact.   My expectation is that if I use all M KernelPCA components (where M is the number of data points, not the number of dimensions), then the inverse transform ought to be exact, just as when I use all N (number of dimensions) components in the linear PCA.   Is that a wrong assumption?

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation for `KernelPCA` around inverses: there is no analytical inverse depending on the kernel, and so they approximate the inverse transform by learning a ridge regression between the PC basis and the original feature space.  You can adjust the regularization parameter for that regression using the parameter `alpha`; setting `alpha=0` in your example produces (nearly, as in `np.allclose`) equal `k_orig` as `train_set` (though presumably a less-faithful inverse for data that isn't your training data).